# Как ограничить ввод на кириллицу?

Tags: javascript

как ограничить ввод кириллицой?

```
function search_largest_substr() {
  let arg = [];
  Array.from(arguments).forEach(a => {
    if (!Array.isArray(a)) return arg.push(a);
    arg = arg.concat(a);
  });

  let str_min = arg[0];
  const list = [];
  for (let n = 1; n < arg.length; n++) {
    if (str_min.length < arg[n].length) {
      list.push(arg[n]);
      continue;
    }
    list.push(str_min);
    str_min = arg[n];
  }
  for (let l = str_min.length; l > 0; l--) {
    for (let p = 0; p < str_min.length - l; p++) {
      let substr = str_min.slice(p, p + l);

      let isFound = true;

      for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].indexOf(substr) >= 0) continue;

        isFound = false;
        break;
      }

      if (isFound) return substr;
    }
  }
  return "";
}
function search_largest_substr() {
  let arg = [];
  Array.from(arguments).forEach(a => {
    if (!Array.isArray(a)) return arg.push(a);
    arg = arg.concat(a);
  });

  let str_min = arg[0];
  const list = [];
  for (let n = 1; n < arg.length; n++) {
    if (str_min.length < arg[n].length) {
      list.push(arg[n]);
      continue;
    }
    list.push(str_min);
    str_min = arg[n];
  }
  for (let l = str_min.length; l > 0; l--) {
    for (let p = 0; p < str_min.length - l; p++) {
      let substr = str_min.slice(p, p + l);

      let isFound = true;

      for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].indexOf(substr) >= 0) continue;

        isFound = false;
        break;
      }

      if (isFound) return substr;
    }
  }
  return "";
}

const results = document.getElementById("results");

var str = search_largest_substr("ABCDEFGH", "ABCDEFG", "ABCDEF");
results.innerHTML +=
  '<hr>в строках ("ABCDEFGH", "ABCDEFG", "ABCDEF") найдена общая подстрока <br>"' +
  str +
  '"';

str = search_largest_substr('ЛАВАР' ,'ЛАВ');
results.innerHTML +=
  '<hr>в строках ("ЛАВАР", "ЛАВ") найдена общая подстрока <br>"' +
  str +
  '"';

str = search_largest_substr("ABCD", "WBCDX");
results.innerHTML +=
  '<hr>в строках ("ABCD", "WBCDX") найдена общая подстрока <br>"' + str + '"';


var str = search_largest_substr("ABCDEFGH", "ABCDEFG", "ABCDEF");
results.innerHTML +=
  '<hr>в строках ("ABCDEFGH", "ABCDEFG", "ABCDEF") найдена общая подстрока <br>"' +
  str +
  '"';

str = search_largest_substr("123445", "12654", "123768");
results.innerHTML +=
  '<hr>в строках ("123445", "12654", "123768") найдена общая подстрока <br>"' +
  str +
  '"';

str = search_largest_substr("ABCD", "WBCDX");
results.innerHTML +=
  '<hr>в строках ("ABCD", "WBCDX") найдена общая подстрока <br>"' + str + '"';
```

И может кто использовал readline, читал доку так и не мог разобраться как используется

Comment: Какой ввод? Где ограничить? Поясните пожалуйста вопрос.

Comment: Ввод в консоле. Чтобы нельзя было вводить русские буквы, выводило бы пыстую строку

Comment: В какой консоли?

Comment: if (process.argv.length < 3) console.log("");
else console.log(lcs(process.argv.slice(2))); я добавил, чтобы после node lcs.js abcd abcd можно получить в ответ bcd